# Defining gRPC RPCs

Tags: service, rpc, grpc

I'm looking for some suggestions here. The usecase is a networking device (like router) with networking operations performed over gRPC.

Let's say there are "n" model objects, like router, interfaces, routing configuration objects like OSPF etc. Every networking operation, like finally be a CRUD on on or many of the model objects.

Now, when defining this over a gRPC service, there seems to be 2 options:

1. Define generic gRPC RPCs, like "SET" and "GET". The parameter will be a list of objects and operations. Like SET((router, update), (interface, update)..
2. Define very specific RPCs. Like "setInterfaceProperty_x", "createOSPFInstance".. And there could be many many such RPCs.

With #2, we are building the application intelligence in the RPCs itself. Every new feature might need new RPCs from this service.

With #1, the RPCs are the means, but the intelligence reside with the application which uses the RPC in a context. The RPC list will be just a very few and doesn't change over time.

What is the preferred approach? Generic RPCs (and keep it very few) or have tens (or more) of operation driven RPCs? I see some opensource projects like P4Runtime take approach #1.

Thanks for your time. I can provide more information if required.

Answer (score 0):

You should use option #2.   This puts your interface contract in the proto, rather than in your application.  You leave your self many open doors by picking option #2 that would be cumbersome or unsupportable otherwise:

- If the API definition of an object doesn't match the internal representation, you need to define a mapping between the two.  Suppose you update your internal code to not need `InterfaceProperty` any more, and it was instead moved to a new field called `BetterInterfaceProperties`.  Option one would force you to keep the old field exposed, while option 2 would allow you to reinterpret the call and do the right thing.
- Fine grained access controls are easier with specific methods.  All users may be able to set `publicProperty`, but only admins can set `dangerousProperty`.  By grouping all the fields into a single call (as in #1), your caller has to reinterpret error messages, while option #2 it's more clear why authorization failed.
- Smaller return values.  Having a method like `getSpecificProperty` will do much less work than `getFullObject`.  As your data model gets more complex, you will have to include more and more data on return messages.  Even if the caller only cares about one thing, they have to wait for all of them.  Consider a Database application.  The database might have to do several unnecessary queries to fill in fields the client will never read.

There are reason to use #1, but they aren't that valuable until you identify what properties go together and are logically a single RPC.  (such as a Get)